# LINQ query from XML and unknown subitems plus container type?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have searched and read across many pages and topics, but have not found the one, that has an answer suited for me. So sorry, if it is there and I'm creating a double post.

Anyway, my problem is reading a XML source and getting data from there in a good format.
My XML is something like that:

```
<Items>
<Item>
    <Type>Book</Type>
    <Name>Jabba the Puppett</Name>
    <Attributes>
        <Author>Author Name</Author>
        <Creator Role="Illustrator">Another Name</Creator>
    </attributes>
</Item>
<Item>
    <Type>Car</Type>
    <Name>BMW</Name>
    <Attributes>
        <Model>520i</Model>
        <Color>Red</Color>
        <Date Role="Year">2009</Date>
        <Date Role="First registration">2010</Date>
        <Color>Red</Color>
    </Attributes>
<Item>
```

My aim is to get data, using LINQ, into some kind of array of container type (containing another container for attributes probably).
The problem part is the attributes, plus there is an option, that they don't exist at all.

I would be very happy when I get result something like this:

```
 foreach (var oneItem in itemlist)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(oneItem.Name +" - "+ oneItem.Type);
            foreach (var attribute in oneItem.Attributes)
                Console.WriteLine(attribute.TagName +attribute.Role+attribute.TagValue);
        }
```

The list of all items and every attribute (of that item) follows to each item.
So the output will be something like:

```
Book - Jabba the Puppett
    Author: Author Name
    Creator Illustrator: Another Name
Car - BMW
    Model: 520i
    Color: Red
    Date Year: 2009
    Date First registration: 2010
```

Comment: Wouldn't deserialization work better? I can work along the lines you described, but what if the structure of the XML were to change?

Comment: You are probably right, but at the moment I am looking the solution I asked. The question is not to find a working solution, I manage to get it work using more than one different techniques. But as I'm not so familiar with LINQ yet, I still would like to know is this possible with one select. Change of XML structure is not important. And of cource, thank You for Your comment.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Hold on a moment, until a test it. I will post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there are a couple of issues here: your XML needs a little fixing (see bellow); your example was listing the `name` first and then the `type` but your output listed them the other way around (easy to change).

```
XElement xml = XElement.Load(myXmlFile);
string tabSpacer = "\t";
foreach (var oneItem in xml.Elements("Item"))
{
    //check if the "Name" element exists
    string name = oneItem.Element("Name") == null ? "" : oneItem.Element("Name").Value;
    //check if the "Type" element exists
    string type = oneItem.Element("Type") == null ? "" : oneItem.Element("Type").Value;
    Console.WriteLine(name + " - " + type);

    //check if the "Item" element contains an "Attributes" element
    if (oneItem.Element("Attributes") != null)
    {
        //assumes at most one "Attribtues" element
        foreach (var attribute in oneItem.Element("Attributes").Elements())
        {
            string role = attribute.Attribute("Role") == null ? "" : attribute.Attribute("Role").Value;
            Console.WriteLine(tabSpacer + attribute.Name + " " + role + ": " + attribute.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the correct XML:

```
<Items>
    <Item>
        <Type>Book</Type>
        <Name>Jabba the Puppett</Name>
        <Attributes>
            <Author>Author Name</Author>
            <Creator Role="Illustrator">Another Name</Creator>
        </Attributes><!--capital A missing-->
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Type>Car</Type>
        <Name>BMW</Name>
        <Attributes>
            <Model>520i</Model>
            <Color>Red</Color>
            <Date Role="Year">2009</Date>
            <Date Role="First registration">2010</Date>
            <Color>Red</Color>
        </Attributes>
    </Item><!--tag not closed-->
</Items><!--tag missing-->
```